# Android MySqli Insert id with sessions in PHP

Tags: php, android-studio

I'm having a problem with an android test application.
I have 2 forms, in the form 1 are entered first the name and then the last name of the user and then in the form 2 their information is inserted.
All this could be done with a single form, but I decided to do it with 2 forms because I want to learn how to use the relationship between the tables in a database.

The first form works, the data is loaded on the DB, but in the second form there is a problem, I do not load the data.

I tried to insert the id of the Query of the first form, and to pass it with the sessions in the second file .php to insert it in the external key.

But it does not work.

Can you tell me why, what am I wrong?

I have 2 tables: 'Persone' and 'Persone2'
The first 'Persone' table has fields: id (PK), Name and Surname (VARCHAR)

The second table 'Persone2' has the following fields: idP2 (PK), FK_persone (Foreign Key), Team, Role and Numbers (VARCHAR)

The .php file of the first form

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

include 'C.php'; 

 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

 $Nome = $_POST['Nome'];
 $Cognome = $_POST['Cognome'];


 $CheckSQL = "SELECT * FROM Persone WHERE Nome = '$Nome'";

 $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$CheckSQL));

 if(isset($check)){

 echo 'Utente già registrato';

 }
else{ 
$Sql_Query = "INSERT INTO Persone (Nome, Cognome) values ('$Nome','$Cognome')";

$People_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
$_SESSION ['People_id'] = $People_id;

 if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query))
{
 echo 'Registration Successfully';
}
else
{
 echo 'Something went wrong';
 }
 }
}
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The .php file of the second form

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

include 'C.php'; 

 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

 $Squadra = $_POST['Squadra'];
 $Ruolo = $_POST['Ruolo'];
 $Numero_maglia = $_POST['Numero_maglia'];


 $CheckSQL = "SELECT * FROM Persone, Persone2 WHERE Persone2.FK_persone = '" . ($_SESSION ['People_id']). "'";;

 $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$CheckSQL));

 if(isset($check)){

 echo 'Utente già registrato';

 }
else{ 
$Sql_Query = "INSERT INTO Persone2 (FK_persone, Squadra, Ruolo, Numero_maglia) values ('" . ($_SESSION ['People_id']). "','$Squadra', '$Ruolo', '$Numero_maglia')";



 if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query))
{
 echo 'Registration Successfully';
}
else
{
 echo 'Something went wrong';
 }
 }
}
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

the Java file of android study related to the second form

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


import android.app.ProgressDialog;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.net.FileNameMap;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText id, squadra, ruolo, numeromaglia;

    private Button registrazionee;

    //REGISTRAZIONE
    String Squadra_Holder, Ruolo_Holder, Numero_Maglia_Holder;
    String finalResult ;
    String HttpURLRegister = "http://provaord.altervista.org/NEW/R22.php";
    Boolean CheckEditText ;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    HttpParse httpParse = new HttpParse();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

       // id = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        squadra = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText7);
        ruolo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        numeromaglia = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);

        registrazionee = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button55);

        registrazionee.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // Checking whether EditText is Empty or Not
                CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot();

                if(CheckEditText){

                    // If EditText is not empty and CheckEditText = True then this block will execute.

                    UserRegisterFunction(Squadra_Holder, Ruolo_Holder, Numero_Maglia_Holder);

                }
                else {

                    // If EditText is empty then this block will execute .
                    Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, "Please fill all form fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }


            }
        });



    }





    //REGISTRAZIONE
    public void CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot(){

        Squadra_Holder = squadra.getText().toString();
        Ruolo_Holder = ruolo.getText().toString();
        Numero_Maglia_Holder = numeromaglia.getText().toString();



        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Squadra_Holder) || TextUtils.isEmpty(Ruolo_Holder) || TextUtils.isEmpty(Numero_Maglia_Holder) )
        {

            CheckEditText = false;

        }
        else {

            CheckEditText = true ;
        }

    }





    //REGISTRATION
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
    public void UserRegisterFunction(final String Squadra, final String Ruolo, final String Numero_maglia){

        class UserRegisterFunctionClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();




                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Activity2.this,"Loading Data",null,true,true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {

                super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);

                progressDialog.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(Activity2.this,httpResponseMsg.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                if(httpResponseMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("Registration Successfully")){

                    finish();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity3.class);



                    startActivity(intent);

                }

            }

            //REGISTRATION
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                hashMap.put("Squadra",params[0]);

                hashMap.put("Ruolo",params[1]);

                hashMap.put("Numero_maglia",params[2]);



                finalResult = httpParse.postRequest(hashMap, HttpURLRegister);

                return finalResult;
            }
        }

        UserRegisterFunctionClass userRegisterFunctionClass = new UserRegisterFunctionClass();

        userRegisterFunctionClass.execute(Squadra, Ruolo, Numero_maglia);
    }





}
```

In summary I can not extract the value of the primary key of the 'Persone' table and then pass the value inside the foreign key 'FK_people' in the table 'Persone2'.
If you know how to pass the primary key of the first table in the foreign key of the second table I would like to know it.
This way of doing it came to mind but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trying to get the last insert ID before you've inserted the row.  So change the code round to something like...

```
if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query))
{
    echo 'Registration Successfully';
    $People_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    $_SESSION ['People_id'] = $People_id;
}
```

In both of your sources, the connection is closed at the end of the script, BUT it should be only closed if it's opened.  Both scripts should move the close into the block of ...

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    // Rest of code...

 mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: 'it does not work' isn't particularly helpful.  Do you get an ID?

Comment: How do you see it? do you want to open the .php file?

Comment: You could add `echo $People_id;` to the above code to check if it's being set.

Comment: Yes, the id is extracted, but I do not understand what I did wrong in the second php file

Comment: Is `$_SESSION ['People_id']` set in the second script?  Do you get any errors? (Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the start of the script to enable errors for now)

Comment: It gives me the error:

Notice: Undefined variable: with in /membri/provaord/NEW/R22.php on line 40

Warning: mysqli_close () expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /membri/provaord/NEW/R22.php on line 40

Comment: Above is the code of the second script, I know that I have not set $ _SESSION ['People_id'], you could also look for me, I do not know where to put it, again under the insertion query?

Comment: I've added an update to the answer, but this points to the second script not picking up that it is a POST

Comment: In the second script, I don't think you need to set `$_SESSION ['People_id']` as it should be set from the first script.

Comment: I did as you said but it does not work, when I press the button on the second form it returns me <br />.
What does it mean? What did I do wrong again?

Comment: Just after the `session_start()` add `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: He tells me: Array ()

Comment: So there is something wrong with how your calling this page.  Can you check it's called the same as your first page.

Comment: Sorry do you mean the Config file?

Comment: I'm assuming it's something in your Android app.  But what is happening is the data isn't reaching your PHP code.

Comment: Perhaps the error is in the syntax of the query for data entry?

Comment: $Sql_Query = "INSERT INTO Persone2 (FK_persone, Squadra, Ruolo, Numero_maglia) values ('" . ($_SESSION ['People_id']). "','$Squadra', '$Ruolo', '$Numero_maglia')";

Comment: All of your values for the query are coming from $_POST, the `print_r()` has shown that this is empty, so it's not reaching any of your code!

Comment: My android code is above, is the same code that I used for the first form, the only difference is that in the second table on 4 fields, only 3 are entered by the android application, the fourth, FK_people is inserted by php.
Instead with the first form all data are entered by the android application

Comment: Maybe after extracting the ID, I should save the application and pass it to the second table from the android application instead of PHP.

But I do not know how, how can I save the ID in the application?

Comment: I am not an Android developer, I don't know how this part works and can just say that you second page isn't receiving any data.

Comment: All right, thank you for your help Nigel Ren, I'm grateful.

I would like to tell you one last thing, if I could pass the data, the code of the second script will you think it's okay? Or do you need to pass data to see if there are any other errors?

Comment: You may find there are further errors, but as your first script is working fine, it's easier to check what is different to help find any errors.